# Html element with height set to 100vh does not always span the whole page height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this strange issue with my body content container. I want it to be as tall as the view port so I set its height to 100vh in the css. It works in all pages except for the one where I try to make a bootstrap grid inside this body content container.

Here you can see how it looks:

[image: Click for image]

The blue-ish div is my body content.

When I zoom all the way out, they blue div's height is indeed 100vh.

[image: SEE IMPORTANT]

Inside of it I've got this

```
<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="row text-center">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
        {
            @Html.Partial("ProductColumn", item)
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

where Html.Partial renders on every iteration something like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 product-column-wrapper">
    <div class="product-column">
        //product title

        <div id="thumbnail-container">
            <a class="d-block mb-4 h-100" asp-route="@WebConstants.Routes.ProductDetails" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" asp-route-title="@Model.Name">
                <img id="thumbnail" src="@Model.ThumbnailSource" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="@Model.Name">
            </a>
        </div>

        //price

      //Edit, Delete buttons
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is some of my css classes:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

footer {

    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 15px;
}

.body-content {
    background: aliceblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

If anyone could help me find out how to stretch the body content in this scenario, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `height: 100vh` try using `min-height: 100vh`. E.g.

```
.body-content {
  background: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic - don't forget to set the correct answer ;)